# Makefile to adjust a variable to multiple values then create a new directories for them?

Tags: makefile, fortran

I have a fortran code using multiple source files in a directory like so, with a makefile that compiles it inside that directory.

```
/TestVersion1
   /input.f
   /otherfiles.f
   /output.lst
   /makefile
```

At the moment I am copying the entire directory and then making a simple adjustment to one double precision variable in the input.f and then compiling using the makefile in each directory.  Values of the variable range from ~300 - 0.01. 
What I'd like is to be able to set the variable with multiple different values in the makefile and then for it to create a system of subdirectories where the value is changed. i.e
Where inside the makefile it would have a predefined list like so:

```
Variable = 1
Variable = 2
etc.
```

And then when a top level makefile is run it create a system of directories with the variable changed and labelled.

```
/TestV1
   /makefile
   /TestVariable1
       /input.f
       /otherfiles.f
       /output.lst
   /TestVariable2
       /input.f
       /otherfiles.f
       /output.lst
```

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512001/how-to-define-a-variable-in-a-makefile-and-then-use-it-within-fortran-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811045/master-makefile-which-runs-make-files-in-subdirectories) I can see its possible to change a variable using a makefile and to use a makefile to run a system of sub-makefiles.

How do I incorporate the two, to copy the source files to a new directory labelled with the variable value, with the input.f changed with that variable value?
Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the multiple directories version working? (without the variable change) I'd rather script this in Python or bash rather than doing the copying in make. The point of the preprocessor method (first link) is that you do not need separate source copies! The change does not stay in the source anyway!

Comment: VladimirF pointed you to the best direction I can think of. Let each tool do what it is best at. Let the makefile do what makefile are best at and let the shell do what the shell is good at. The shell is very good at doing stuff like copying file, creating hierarchy of directories, etc. And it can be done with python too as mentionned by Vladimir. The risk of doing everything with the makefile is that you could have something too complicated where it can be simple.

Comment: In the first place, when do you use your input file? Is it an included file (included in other source files)? is it used by the makefile? or is it used a runtime when you run the compiled program?

Comment: Why not just have the program read the variable from a text file or stdin?  Compile the executable once and run it for as many different values as you want.  Or is the real problem more complicated than the Q suggests?